# Ado.Net dll working without client db installation

Tags: .net, f#, ado.net, sap-ase

I have an ADO.NET dll that I often add to my C# or F# .Net projects and I see that I can deliver the compiled executable files to a server or a workstation, where there is no db client software installed.

Today I've noticed that when I deploy a simple project to a specific server, which contains an old db client setup, my executable behaves differently and it's clear that this is due to a bug somewhere in the ado.net provider implementation.

I don't think that the specific details of the bug are relevant, anyway the point is that a command parameter doesn't work when the underlying db type is a VARCHAR, while a command parameter for a date column is correctly interpreted (see more below, but I guess you can skip the details in order to answer the general, main question).

This is *very odd* to me: how is it possible that a seemingly standalone ADO.NET dll behaves differently when some client software is installed?
If this managed ADO.NET dll would require the presence somewhere of an unmanaged dll, shouldn't it throw an exception when I deploy my projects to workstations without any setup?

Is my reasoning - at least in principle - correct?

### TL;DR

I've added a reference to `Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient` from my ADO.NET solution and I'm selecting a `DataTable` (btw, same problem also if I write the equivalent code with a `DataReader`)

```
use cn = new AseConnection(connString) 
let cmd = new AseCommand(sql, cn)
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars)
let da = new AseDataAdapter(cmd) 
let ds = new DataSet()
cn.Open() 
let i = da.Fill(ds) 
printfn "DB Tables #: %i" ds.Tables.Count
let rows = ds.Tables.[0].Select()
printfn "erro? %b name %s rows %i" 
    ds.Tables.[0].HasErrors ds.Tables.[0].TableName rows.Length
```

through a command sql `"SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW WHERE status = @MyStatus "` with one parameter `AseParameter("@MyStatus", "TEST" )` whose DB type is `VARCHAR(255)`.

It is **very odd** that this simple `AseParameter` (just based on a string) doesn't work *on some old servers*: no rows are selected (and they should be, of course). It is also odd that filters by date - instead - work as expected.

The only (meaningful?) difference I've found on these servers is that they have an older ODBC driver version, but I believe it shouldn't be related, since this ADO.NET connection is **not** based on ODBC! Afaik I'm pretty sure the `Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient` dll doesn't rely on any other Sybase Client installation, is it correct?

Is there any expert of ADO.NET with Sybase ASE who can cast light over this?

Answer (score 0):

> how is it possible that a seemingly standalone ADO.NET dll behaves differently when some client software is installed?

It is an unintended bug. I've found that the redistributable `Sybase.AdoNet45.AseClient.dll` works as expected *without any other Sybase files* and this **bug** has been **fixed**.

> It is very odd that this simple AseParameter (just based on a string) doesn't work on some old servers

That was not happening only on some old servers, but also on new ones without any Sybase client setup. Therefore in that `Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient` there is some *unintended reference* to other client software, in this case the fact that the client software is missing does not trigger an exception (it is not supposed to be present and it is not linked as a dependence indeed) but a bug.

> I'm pretty sure the Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient dll doesn't rely on any
>   other Sybase Client installation, is it correct?

and

> If this managed ADO.NET dll would require the presence somewhere of an
>   unmanaged dll, shouldn't it throw an exception when I deploy my
>   projects to workstations without any setup?

Yes, newer versions of ADO.NET dlls do not require other unmanaged components, older versions did (in case unamanged dll are missing older sybase ado.net dll throw exceptions).

**Out of curiosity**, an older version than the one of my original question (plus the unmanaged dlls) works without this bug, but it throws a `StackOverflowException` unless one changes the `Parameters.AddRange` into

```
pars |> Seq.iter (fun (par: AseParameter) -> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(par.ParameterName, par.Value) |> ignore)
```

As I stated at the beginning of the answer, the latest .Net 4.5 `Sybase.AdoNet45.AseClient.dll` version works without this bug (and also with the unchanged original `cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars)`)